# What type of grappling hook does Cap have in Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

During the final fight scene between Stark, Buck, and himself, Cap utilizes some sort of grappling gun akin to Batman. Is this a real life thing, or was it invented purely for the movie?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They certainly come that small but since Iron Man almost certainly CGI in those shots it's unlikely to have been a functional device. https://countycomm.com/products/grappling-hook

Comment: Well I was referring to the concept as a whole.

Comment: I understand but that's not what you actually *said*. Anyway, pleased you got an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Grappling hooks are still not quite real. Devices like the one Captain America or Batman use are still not able to be created with conventional technologies. It is being developed and it can be considered one of those near-technologies just waiting for the right degree of miniaturization necessary to make it real.

Grappling hooks are a cool movie device which allows non-flying heroes the ability to get around. This technology is not yet real but there are real universities whose research teams ARE developing such technology for the military to use.

BYU engineering students have developed a "Batman"-like grappling hook device for the United States Air Force. If they are successful, their goal would create a grapple which could fly 90 feet and allow them to climb up a vertical surface.

Testing and experimentation are ongoing by various agencies for use in military, police and naval operations.

Comment: Thank you. Very detailed too, I may add. Also, weren't you the same guy who calculated how much it would cost to be Batman lol?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am glad to help.